# SSL certificate installation issue

Tags: ssl-certificate

After changing ssl certificate authority from **Thawte** to **DigiCert**.

SSL certificate installation issue.

After installing new DigiCert ssl certificate in our server. It is still referring to old Thawte ssl certificate even though we removed old certificate from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have another vhost file using the old certificate , please remove that from your . Also make sure you properly restart apache after adding the new certificate .

To check your installation you can use the tool below

[Thawte certificate checker](https://ssltools.thawte.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

To see what certificate you are using, you can use the following tool [Tool](https://www.digicert.com/help/)

This tool will allow you to check what certificate is installed on your server. Then, you can use the utility tool [utility tool](https://www.digicert.com/util/)

You will be able to see all of the certs from your local machine or server. If you don't see the certificate there, you can import your certificate with that tool. If the utility tool mentions that your private key doesn't match, you will have to recreate the CSR with the utility tool and you will have to reissue your cert. **If you reissue your cert, you will not invalidate the original request.**